# Code-first Entity Framework not picking up web.config connection string when initializing

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have been using code-first entity framework. I have defined a connection in the web.config, with name matching the class name of my DbContext (in this example 'MyDbContext').

EF uses this connection with no problems when the database exists.

However, if I delete the database (to force EF to re-create it) EF creates the database on the local Sql Express server instead.

If I specify the full connection string in the DbContext class constructor like

```cs
    public class ReykerSCPContext : DbContext
{
public ReykerSCPContext() : 
    base("Server=tcp:MyDBSErver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDB;User ID=#######;Password=#######;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;PersistSecurityInfo=True;") { }
}
```

then the database is created correctly on the server of choice. Great!

Can anyone tell me if this is correct behaviour as I am bashing my brains out. I would like it all to work from the web.config, so I don't need to necessarily rebuild and remember to change settings in code etc..

Comment: I believe that is normal and EF by default goes to the local sql instance.   I'll have to spin up one of my projects to check.  You can google on Julie Lerman and see her blog/videos on how EF code first behaves and how to change it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Whether the database exists or not the connectionString from the config is being used. Have you tried (as a workaround) passing the connection string name to the DbContext ctor (e.g. base("name={Your connection string}")? If not try if it works. Also what version of EF are you on?

Comment: Your constructor MyDbContext has different name than your class name ReykerSCPContext , is that the problem?

Comment: Well spotted. My actual code is correct though. I will update the question.

Comment: From your description, it would seem that there is some misconfiguration and possibly the application is always connecting to the default localhost server. Could you post the relevant connectionString snippet from your web.config or app.config?

Comment: Please paste your web.config code here.  Also, please confirm that you are modifying the web.config at the root of your application.  EF will find configuration for the app domain it is running in -- for example, if you're running a website with a separate data access project EF will use configuration from the website's web.config and NOT configuration defined in the data access project.

Comment: Have you managed t solve the problem? I'm facing exactly the same problem -(

Comment: Same problem here.  Any joy in fixing?

Comment: Not really. I ended up with belt and braces. Setting it in web.config and in code. However I was also using the Microsoft Membership provider which turns out to have it's own database generation. I think this basically screwed with the EF's process and gave up on it.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext {
    public EFDbContext() : base("EFDbContext") {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

You should have the connection string by the name of your context class in the web.config and that will do it. The web.config should be in root.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = ITSDB; Integrated Security = true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
update-database -v
```

and it shows it is using IIS express instance instead of the value from the Web.Config , it means EF is confused when the local IIS express instance is running.

I had the same issue and was resolved by stop/delete IIS express.

```
"sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0"

"sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0”
```

Hop that helps someone!